# Accessing high dimension tables - clearer way to index the different dimensions?

Tags: r

I was wondering if there is a clearer easier way of accessing different dimensions of a table.

I have this code

```
datasettable = addmargins(
  table(dataset[c('observer','condition','stimulus1', 'stimulus2','response')]), 
  4, FUN = sum)
```

And I access it the following way:

```
datasettable[,'u',1,'sum',]
```

However, I find accessing it this way somewhat confusing. Because the indices for the different dimensions are separated by a comma it is easy to confuse the indices for the separate dimensions.

Is there a way to define the indices to the different dimensions by name( especially important for numerical indices) such as with

```
datasettable ['obsever'=='ALL','condition'=='u',
  'stimulus1'==1, 'stimulus2'=='sum','response'=='ALL']
```

Comment: An indexable object with five index positions is not a "table". You can index n-dimensional arrays with n-column matrices, rather than specifying every dimension within commas - that might be what you're after but as it stands this question is very unclear

Comment: I don't think the question is unclear: it's basically "is there a way to index/subset an array without using the [,,,] syntax which identifies the dimensions only by their order?"  @rafalotufo's answer applies to data frames, not arrays.  You could in principle expand the array to a data frame (as.data.frame.table), subset, and then collapse it back to an array (table/tapply) -- ugh.  An answer might be hackable but I don't have one yet.

Comment: Adding to the possible unclarity, your code to create `datasettable` is missing a parenthesis.

Comment: @mdsumner: Why do you say it's not a table?  See `class(table(data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3)))`; seems to be a table to me.

Comment: I don't get your use of five index slots in the last two lines of code, which suggests a 5D array. Obviously the output of table() will be of class "table", but in the sense you want to subset it (I think) it's just an array - I can see that I misunderstood that originally. There's no reason not to provide example data so we can run your code

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I have been wondering about this issue for a while. I did attempt various conversions but none provided a simple solution. My apology for not including the data (it's not a small set), and also for my use of nomenclature. The term table may not be the best to describe the structure and I chose it because the structure was a product of a table function. There was an extra parenthesis that i took off. Thanks you for sharing my frustration and determination against r idiosyncrasies !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make up some data (hint: including data of your own helps you get better answers; `dput` can be a great tool for that).

```
dataset <- expand.grid(observer=LETTERS[1:3], condition=c("u","v"), 
                       stimulus1=1:2, stimulus2=1:2)
set.seed(5)
dataset$response <- sample(1:4, nrow(dataset), replace=TRUE)
datasettable <- addmargins(table(dataset), 4, FUN = sum)
```

What you suggest is this:

```
> datasettable[,'u',1,'sum',]
        response
observer 1 2 3 4
       A 1 1 0 0
       B 0 0 2 0
       C 0 1 0 1
```

I'd probably get the total without first converting to a table, perhaps using the `reshape` package, like this:

```
> library(reshape)
> dw <- cast(dataset, condition + stimulus1 + observer ~ response, 
             fun.aggregate=length, value="stimulus2")
> subset(dw, condition=="u" & stimulus1==1)
  condition stimulus1 observer 1 2 3 4
1         u         1        A 1 1 0 0
2         u         1        B 0 0 2 0
3         u         1        C 0 1 0 1
```

But to answer your question, no, I don't think there's an alternate way built in to access parts of a table, but you could certainly build one, maybe like this:

```
tableaccess <- function(tabl, ...) {
  d <- list(...)
  vv <- c(list(tabl), as.list(rep(TRUE, length(dim(tabl)))))
  vv[match(names(d), names(dimnames(datasettable)))+1] <- d
  do.call(`[`, vv)
}
```

with a result of

```
> tableaccess(datasettable, condition='u', stimulus1=1, stimulus2='sum')
        response
observer 1 2 3 4
       A 1 1 0 0
       B 0 0 2 0
       C 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you described, you can use `subset` function:

```
subset(datasettable, observer == 'ALL' & condition == 'u' &
       stimulus1 == 1 & stimulus2 == 'sum' & response == 'ALL')
```

This, of course, assumes `datasettable` is a `data.frame`.

Comment: In this case `datasettable` isn't a `data.frame` though, it's a 5-dimensional array.